# Does main() need a docstring?

Tags: python, documentation, pep8

I always thought that a `main()` function (as called from `if __name__ == '__main__'`)doesn't need a docstring, since

1. Docstrings can be seen when calling a function from within python, but outside the module, but `main()` is usually only called from the command line (where the docstring is not accessible).
2. The idea of `main()` should be well enough understood that it need no documentation.

Yet, from pep8:

> Write docstrings for all public modules, functions, classes, and methods. Docstrings are not necessary for non-public methods, but you should have a comment that describes what the method does. This comment should appear after the "def" line.

Which line of thought wins out?

Comment: Do you mean in just a function called `main()` or a docstring for `if __name__ == '__main__'`

Comment: Either way, check out http://blog.dolphm.com/pep257-good-python-docstrings-by-example/ it shows examples of both

Comment: The one that explains what your `main()` *is actually doing*.

Comment: "The idea of main() should be well enough understood that it need no documentation." - you're saying you don't want to document a thing because people should already understand it? Where is this understanding supposed to come from, if it's not going to come from the documentation?

Comment: Sorry what I meant by main being well understood is that, often, function names can be ambiguous, and a docstring can help clarify the coder's intention. That aspect is not needed

Comment: That aspect is *definitely* needed. The name "main" only communicates the main-ness of the function, not what the function *actually does*.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The reason pep8 doesn't require docstrings for private functions is because the people who will be trying to figure out how to use it will be looking at the code directly, so the nice aspects of e.g. being able to use doc(func) are less helpful. Similarly, the people using your `main` are more likely to be looking at the output of `--help` on the command line than any docstrings.

Comment: `main()` usually does what's in the module docstring.

Comment: The dolphm blog link above is stale. Google turns up https://gist.github.com/dolph/39d8f70cab6afbac8c01.